# Extjs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null

Tags: extjs

When I try to destroy an Extjs Panel I query the panel like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('panel-117').destroy();
```

Then I get that error.

When I print (console) the Panel I see it:

```
ctor {initialConfig: {…}, $iid: 605, id: "panel-117", autoGenId: true, protoEl: null, …}
```

[image]

[image]

So I render the 'panel-117' (for example) and it's children components into the 'div' and when the user closes the widow I need to manually destroy those panels.

Any Idea?

Comment: It would be great if you share console screen with whole object expanded. But by given info,this means component object is still present , but element is destroyed. I have came across this thing many times.

Comment: How you managed to solve that?

Comment: No idea without some bug reproduction code. May you proved fiddle.sencha.com sample? Is „panel-117“ autogenerated ID? If YES, it is very bad practice to access the component in this way. Rendering panel into a div is also not necessary, ExtJs has appropriate layout mechanisms for that.